# Sorting a list using custom parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> Here is my code :

```
import java.util.List;

import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.filter.SearchRequestService;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchException;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProvider;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchRequest;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchResults;
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter;


class IssueTest{

    String  id;
    String type;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public IssueTest(String id,String type)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;

    }


}


public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

     static List<IssueTest> issues; 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        test t = new test();


    }

    public test ()
    {

        IssueTest i = new IssueTest("B-1", "bug");
        issues.add(i);
        IssueTest j = new IssueTest("S-1", "story");
        issues.add(j);
        IssueTest k = new IssueTest("T-1", "task");
        issues.add(k);
        IssueTest l = new IssueTest("T-2", "task");
        issues.add(l);
        IssueTest m = new IssueTest("E-1", "epic");
        issues.add(m);
        IssueTest n = new IssueTest("E-2", "epic");
        issues.add(n);
        IssueTest o = new IssueTest("T-3", "task");
        issues.add(o);
        IssueTest p = new IssueTest("S-2", "story");
        issues.add(p);
        IssueTest q = new IssueTest("B-2", "bug");
        issues.add(q);
        IssueTest r = new IssueTest("B-3", "bug");
        issues.add(r);

    }


}
```

> I want to sort this list according to the "**type**" .  I want all objects
>   in the order of - **tasks** then **bugs** then **story** then **epic**

Comment: and the results you have gotten so far are what?  Further what have you tried to validate that your implementation is correct / incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to write a custom `Comparator` to implement that ordering.  This is going to be a bit complicated, unfortunately, without third-party libraries...especially if you're not on Java 7.

```
Comparator<IssueTest> comparator = new Comparator<IssueTest>() {
  private int getStringPosition(String str) {
    if(str.equals("task")) {
      return 0;
    } else if (str.equals("bug")) {
      return 1;
    } else if (str.equals("story")) {
      return 2;
    } else if (str.equals("epic")) {
      return 3;
    } else {
      throw new AssertionError();
    }
  }
  public int compare(IssueTest a, IssueTest b) {
    return getStringPosition(a.getType()) - getStringPosition(b.getType());
  }
};
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

If you used an enum instead of string types, this would be much easier, though.

If you can use third-party libraries, this might be a bit simpler with Guava:

```
Ordering<String> typeOrdering = Ordering.explicit("task", "bug", "story", "epic");
Ordering<IssueTest> issueTestOrdering =
 typeOrdering.onResultOf(new Function<IssueTest, String>() {
   public String apply(IssueTest it) {return it.getType(); }
 });
Collections.sort(list, issueTestOrdering);
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: I cannot use external libraries . Please can you show without this

Answer (score 2):

You can define a comparator method and use `Collections.sort(lst)`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

If that's the *only* way you want to ever sort a list of `IssueTest` objects, then the right way would be to implement `Comparable`.

It is well explained on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

If you'd want to sort by different keys in different places, don't make `IssueTest` implement `Comparable`, but make a set of classes that implement `Comparator<IssueTest>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class IssueComparator implements Comparator<IssueTest>{

    @Override
    public int compare(IssueTest issue1, IssueTest issue2) {

        String type1 = issue1.getType();
        String type2 = issue2.getType();

        if (type1.length() > type2.length() ){
            return +1;
        }else if (type1.length() < type2.length() ){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Obviously length is not an appropriate criterion to use,  The above is to illustrate how an implementation of `Comparator` can be completed.

Comment: It makes a lot more sense to use the `compareTo` method already present on the `String` class; `type1.compareTo(type2)`. Of course, you may want to check for nulls and you may want to store it so you can check the other fields if the result is null.

Comment: @Thor84no sure equally valid point, I am assuming that String is the correct object type in his domain object.  I did however want to give OP an explanation as to how Comparator can be implemented as it is important to know.